# Lodash function for splitting collection into keyed subcollections

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

Below is an example blackbox view of something like what I'd like to do.

```
keyMany (arr: any[], cbk: (any) => string[])
  given that arr === [e1, e2, e3] (but could be any length);
  given cbk(e1) -> ['foo'];
  given cbk(e2) -> ['foo', 'bar'];
  given cbk(e3) -> ['baz', 'bar'];
```

then

```
output: {
  foo: [e1, e2],
  bar: [e2, e3],
  baz: [e3]
}
```

To summarize what is happening, the first argument which is a collection, applies `cbk` on an element-wise basis to determine which keys in an output that element should be a part of. An element may be a part of multiple output key sets.

Notice that:

1. Since `cbk` applied to `e1` results in just `foo`, `e1` only participates in output key set `foo`.
2. Since `cbk` applied to `e2` results in `foo` & `bar`, `e2` is in output key sets `foo` & `bar`.
3. Likewise for `e3`, just for key sets `bar` & `baz` instead.

Ideally, `e`'s in the output collection, if objects, would be referentially equivalent to `e`'s in the input collection.

Note that: the first input

**My question is: does something like this already exist in Lodash? Favored answers to this question are yes with a version number, or no.**

As an aside, if this behavior isn't easily achievable, or this seems valuable, I've currently got a PR on Lodash right now to add a `keyMany` API:
https://github.com/lodash/lodash/pull/4149/commits/cfe2918c905481f6f713be0a4e10cd4b60d32c4a

Comment: Please format your question appropriately, it's hard to tell if some of it is actual code or pseudocode.

Comment: Tbh i don't understand your question

Comment: I think this isn't the right forum to ask: if you think it is useful and should be added to the lodash library, talk to the owners of the repo instead (I can see that you've opened a PR, so just be patient and wait for community feedback). If you need review of your code you can ask on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @JackBashford thanks, valid

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you want to build a dictionary with keys from sub-array values that result from a custom callback function.

In the case of your data/input, one option is to use `Array#reduce()` to achieve this, as detailed below:

```js
// Mock setup data to support code snippet
var e1 = '0', e2 = '1', e3 = '2';
// Mock setup function to support code snippet
var cbk = (arg) => {
  switch(arg) {
    case e1: return ['a'];
    case e2: return ['a','b'];
    case e3: return ['b','c'];
  }
}

// Your input
var inputs = [e1,e2,e3];

// Process to aquire desired output
var output = inputs.reduce((result, inputValue) => {
  
  // Iterate callback result of each input value
  cbk(inputValue).forEach(cbkItem => {
    
    // Aquire array new or existing array that corresponds 
    // to this callback result's value (ie 'a', 'c', etc)
    var callbackResultArray = (result[ cbkItem ] || []);
    
    // Add current input value to callback result array
    callbackResultArray.push(inputValue);
    
    // Update result map with callback result array
    result[ cbkItem ] = callbackResultArray;
  
  });
  
  return result;

}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Yeah, @Denny, you're definitely on the right track. This is very similar to my approach. Glad I'm not insane. I was wondering more if anyone knew whether Lodash did this out of the box.

Comment: Perhaps we're both insane ;-)